# Crash on updating position of Box2D body based on Cocos2d sprite

Tags: cocos2d-x, box2d

this is how I remove my body from the world: `_world->DestroyBody(spriteBody);`

In my game, I constantly create Cocos2d Sprite and Box2D Body and I also constantly delete them.

However, when I try to `LOG("%d", _world->GetBodyCount());` the number is increasing and never decrease.

I think `_world->DestroyBody(spriteBody);` might not completely delete my Box2D body.

This is my delete method.

```
void GameScene::deleteSprite(Sprite *sprite){

b2Body *spriteBody = NULL;
for(b2Body *b = _world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext()) {
    if (b->GetUserData() != NULL) {
        Sprite *curSprite = (Sprite *)b->GetUserData();
        if (sprite == curSprite) {
            log("3");
            spriteBody = b;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (spriteBody != NULL) {
    //spriteBody->SetUserData(NULL);
    //b2Fixture* f = spriteBody->GetFixtureList();
    //spriteBody->DestroyFixture(f);
    spriteBody->GetWorld()->DestroyBody(spriteBody);
}
sprite->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
}
```

Create method - I took this code from GMTDev and Raywenderlich. Box2D for collision detection only

```
 void GameScene::addBoxBodyForSprite( Sprite *sprite, int iNumVerts, b2Vec2 verts[] ){

    if( _world==NULL )
        return;

    Point pos = sprite->getPosition();
    Size size = sprite->getContentSize();

    b2BodyDef spriteBodyDef;
    spriteBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    spriteBodyDef.position.Set(pos.x/PTM_RATIO, pos.y/PTM_RATIO);
    spriteBodyDef.userData = sprite;
    b2Body *spriteBody = _world->CreateBody(&spriteBodyDef);

    b2PolygonShape spriteShape;

    if( iNumVerts!=0 )
    {
        spriteShape.Set(verts, iNumVerts);
        b2FixtureDef spriteShapeDef;
        spriteShapeDef.shape = &spriteShape;
        spriteShapeDef.density = 10.0;
        spriteShapeDef.isSensor = true;

        spriteBody->CreateFixture(&spriteShapeDef);
    }
    else
    {
        // No Vertice supplied so just make a box round the sprite
        b2BodyDef spriteBodyDef;
        spriteBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
        spriteBodyDef.position.Set( pos.x/PTM_RATIO, pos.y/PTM_RATIO );
        spriteBodyDef.userData = sprite;
        b2Body *spriteBody = _world->CreateBody( &spriteBodyDef );

        b2PolygonShape spriteShape;
        spriteShape.SetAsBox( size.width/PTM_RATIO/2, size.height/PTM_RATIO/2 );
        b2FixtureDef spriteShapeDef;
        spriteShapeDef.shape = &spriteShape;
        spriteShapeDef.density = 10.0;
        spriteShapeDef.isSensor = true;                     // isSensor true when you want to know when objects will collide without triggering a box2d collision response
        spriteBody->CreateFixture( &spriteShapeDef );
    }

}
```

Thanks !!

Comment: Where are you trying to delete these bodies? where is this method deleteSprite called?

Comment: @UmeshSharma Thanks for the response. What I'm trying to do is like Flappy Bird. The obstacle move from Right to Left of the screen. I have a function that schedule every frame to check whether that obstacle leave the screen. When the obstacle leave the screen, I call the method deleteSprite(obstacle);

Comment: DestroyBody does what it says. I think you just keep adding more bodies than you destroy.

Comment: @pupuupup i agree with LearnCocos2d. Either your method for creation is called more times than expected or it is been called in some scheduler. (May be where you are checkin the code.). For a similiar kind of code i have set a flag in tick. And i set it true if a body deletes and at end of tick the method for creating the new bodies is called. At the start of tick the flag is always false. May be you can try that

Comment: @LearnCocos2D
Wow. Thank you very much!!! That should be it.

Comment: @pupuupup So does that solves your issue?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I create 1 body for 1 sprite, but why when I LOG("%d", _world->GetBodyList()); I got 2 for just 1 creation? Is this normal? or Is my create method wrong?

Comment: @UmeshSharma I'm figuring out whether my create method for Box2D object is wrong. When I create 1 body for 1 sprite, the _world->GetBodyList() return 2 for just 1 creation. Is this normal?

Comment: No it is not. But there would be one body of your bird/character already present. how many times have you called world->CreateBody ?

Comment: @UmeshSharma I have added my create method in my question. This is how I create the body. I call it once in the init method for the bird. By the way, I'm new to stack overflow.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Try to debug it. Maybe you find your problem. This happened with me once and i have alreay told you what i have tried.

Comment: @UmeshSharma Hey, I know it now. There is _world->CreateBody twice in my create method. Thank you very much .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved from the help of @UmeshSharma and @LearnCocos2D

in the create method that I got from GMTDev has some mistakes where the function _world->CreateBody is used twice (when iNumVerts == 0)

Therefore, when I delete my body and sprite. There is actually another body remaining for that sprite. And then it crash on the update where the Box2D body cannot find its Cocos2d sprite.